# Who knows what a token collection interface is?

Tags: erc-721, ipfs, nft

I'm new to blockchain development. I'm reading a tutorial on developing an NFT platform and it talks about a token collection interface. Can anyone explain to me what this is. Let's say you have a platform that has users who upload digital photos of their artwork and buyers who buy/bid on the platform? Thanks